# How to instantiate a class using switch and then access and change its properties

Tags: c#, oop, object, switch-statement

Working on a choose your adventure game for a final project, but I've run into an issue when trying to have the player choose a class. When the player chooses their class I want the switch statement to instantiate a new object of that class for me to access and subsequently change its properties (i.e. lower HP when hit or raise it when using a potion). Right now it doesn't appear that the properties save after a change.

Definition of the player class:

```
public class Player
{
    internal int maxPlayerHealth;
    internal int currentPlayerHealth;
    internal int playerDamage;
    internal int playerDef;
    internal int playerAgility;
    internal int playerStrength;
    internal int playerExperience;

    public Player()
    {
    }

    public Player(int maxHp, int currentHp, int dmg, int def, int agil, int str, int exp)
    {
        maxPlayerHealth = maxHp;
        currentPlayerHealth = currentHp;
        playerDamage = dmg;
        playerDef = def;
        playerAgility = agil;
        playerStrength = str;
        playerExperience = exp;
    }


    private int MaxPlayerHealth { get => maxPlayerHealth;}
    private int CurrentPlayerHealth { get => currentPlayerHealth; set => currentPlayerHealth = value;}
    private int PlayerDamage { get => playerDamage;}
    private int PlayerDef { get => playerDef; }
    private int PlayerAgility { get => playerAgility; }
    private int PlayerStrength { get => playerStrength;}
    private int PlayerExperience { get => playerExperience;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Health: " + currentPlayerHealth;
    }

    public int DamageTaken(int monsterDMG)
    {
        currentPlayerHealth = currentPlayerHealth - monsterDMG;
        return currentPlayerHealth;
    }
}
```

Code to have player choose their class:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace _350_final_project
{
    public class Story
    {
        static Player chosenClass;

        public Player ChooseClass(string choice)
        {
            switch (choice.ToLower())
            {
                case "warrior":
                    chosenClass = new Player()
                    {
                        maxPlayerHealth = 150,
                        currentPlayerHealth = 150,
                        playerDamage = 35,
                        playerDef = 120,
                        playerStrength = 95,
                        playerAgility = 30,
                        playerExperience = 0
                    };
                    WriteLine("You have chosen the path of the Warrior. Live by the sword. Die by the sword! \n");
                    return chosenClass;

                case "theif":
                    chosenClass = new Player()
                    {
                        maxPlayerHealth = 85,
                        currentPlayerHealth = 85,
                        playerDamage = 27,
                        playerDef = 43,
                        playerStrength = 20,
                        playerAgility = 125,
                        playerExperience = 0
                    };
                    WriteLine("You have chosen to lurk in the shadows as a theif \n");
                    return chosenClass;

                case "gunner":
                    chosenClass = new Player()
                    {
                        maxPlayerHealth = 70,
                        currentPlayerHealth = 70,
                        playerDamage = 40,
                        playerDef = 75,
                        playerStrength = 60,
                        playerAgility = 110,
                        playerExperience = 0
                    };
                    WriteLine("You have chosen the way of the gunner, shoot with your mind not your eye \n");
                    return chosenClass;

                default:
                  return null;
        }
    }

    public void Beginning(string playerName, string playerClass)
    {
        WriteLine("Valiant {0}, It is time to begin your journey", playerName);
        WriteLine("We begin in the hall of heroes, the queen has tasked you with destorying the dragon \n" +
                  " that resides at the tower on the edge of the kingdom. To bein your journey pick a direction in which to go. \n" +
                  "Will you venture north, east or west?");
        string directionDecision = ReadLine();

        WriteLine("You head {0}, steadily making your way toward {1}", directionDecision, Randomize.RandomizeLocation().Name);
        WriteLine("After several long miles you come across a fork in the road with no signs pointing you to your destination. \n " +
                  "Your map is useless and due to your illpreparedness supplies are running short. Which direction will you go? \n" +
                  "North, East, or West?:");
        directionDecision = ReadLine();

        WriteLine("Setting your sights to the {0} you soldier on. As you take a look at your surroundings and you suddenly " +
                  "notice you're not alone", directionDecision);
        Encounter.StartBattle(playerClass, chosenClass);
     }
   }
}
```

Code to start a battle:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Threading;

namespace _350_final_project
{
    public class Encounter
    {
        private static int encounterCounter = Randomize.NumberGenerator(1, 10) % 2;

    //public static void GenerateEncounter (string playerClass,Player classChosen)
    //{
    //    if (encounterCounter == 0)
    //    {
    //        StartBattle(playerClass, classChosen);
    //    }
    //}

    public void StartBattle(string playerClass, Player chosenClass)
    {
        Monster currentMonster = Randomize.RandomizeMonster();
        string action;
        WriteLine("AMBUSH! A {0} appears to challenge you adventurer!", currentMonster.Name);

        switch (playerClass)
        {
            case "warrior":
                WriteLine("You quickly draw your greatsword and stand at the ready");
                action = "You drag your sword in a great arc!";
                EncounterBattle(currentMonster, chosenClass, action);
                break;
            case "theif":
                WriteLine("You swiftly load your gun, eyes glaring over the barrell");
                action = "You fire your weapon with extreme accuracy!";
                EncounterBattle(currentMonster, chosenClass, action);
                break;
            case "gunner":
                WriteLine("You pull both daggers from your cloak and being to toss them from palm to palm");
                action = "You dash forward, daggers a silver blur!";
                EncounterBattle(currentMonster, chosenClass, action);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    public void EncounterBattle(Monster monster, Player chosenClass, string action)
    {
        while (monster.CurrentHp > 0 || chosenClass.currentPlayerHealth > 0)
        {
            int monsterHitMissCounter = Randomize.NumberGenerator(1, 10) % 2;

            WriteLine("{0}{1}", monster.Name, monster.Attack);

            if (monsterHitMissCounter != 0)
            {
                WriteLine("{0}'s attack hits, you take {1} damage", monster.Name, monster.MaxDamage);

                WriteLine("Your current health is {0}", chosenClass.DamageTaken(monster.MaxDamage));
                ReadKey();
            }

            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                WriteLine("\n {0} missed!", monster.Name);
                ReadKey();
            }
            int playerHitMissCounter = Randomize.NumberGenerator(1, 10) % 2;
            if (playerHitMissCounter != 0)
            {
                WriteLine("Your attacked missed!");
                ReadKey();
            } else
            {
                WriteLine("You {0}, {1} takes {2} damage", action, monster.Name, chosenClass.playerDamage);

                WriteLine("{0}'s current health is {1}", monster.Name, monster.MonsterDamageTaken(chosenClass.playerDamage));
                ReadKey();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: "When the player chooses their class I want the switch statement to instantiate a new object" - You mark `Player` as static, so you will not be able to instantiate a new Player-object.

Comment: @thesystem Of course he can instantiate a new Player instance. He never does as far as I can see, and the field shouldn't be static, but it's not `readonly`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Can you explain me, how can he instantiate a static class? EDIT: This line: `choosenClass = new Player()` ...seems like an attempt to instantiate the Player-class to me.

Comment: OP, you never call `ChooseClass()` and you never use the `Player` object for anything. Who calls `Beginning()`? Who passes in its parameters? Please show enough code to reproduce what you're seeing. You use `static` far too often, by the way.

Comment: @thesystem The definition of `Player` isn't included. He has a static field of that type, and a static method which returns that type. His code instantiates `Player` and he is talking about a *runtime* issue. Hence the code compiles. You're mistaken.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm happy to be mistaken - I'm not arguing to be right, but in the first case I was trying to help him to my best knowledge, and in the second case I was simply trying to understand your argumentation. Have a good day.

Comment: @thesystem Player itself is not declared as a static class (otherwise the `choosenClass = new Player()` wouldn't compile). Just the "pointer" `static Player choosenClass` is declared as static (that doesn't prevent other instances of Player to be created)

Comment: @VladimirPavelka Thanks for the explanation, it makes more sense now. I'm just wondering, why would you mark the pointer as static then?

Comment: Please include definition of Player class.

Comment: @thesystem you would mark member (Player) static so that all instances of the owner class (Story) share the same instance of that member (Player). i.e. all stories have/point to the same player in this case. The scary part (of static) is, later, if any of the story instances overwrite the `Player chosenClass`, it will get overwritten in all story instances. Imagine you are a scared little instance of the Story class, and suddenly, out of nowhere, your `*private* static Player chosenClass` get's overwritten, without you exposing a public setter or having any control over it. Hours of fun!